# How to import SlackWebHookOperator in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, slack

I want to integrate Slack alert messages when a task fail in Airflow with SlackWebHookOperator. I have issue with the import of the operator.

In this tutorial (https://medium.com/datareply/integrating-slack-alerts-in-airflow-c9dcd155105) the author mentions there are 2 ways to achieve this. The first implementation is using slack legacy tokens which can be deprecated anytime and the second is using slack webhook which is the implementation I want. The author mentions to install slack dependencies, quoted by the author "Remember to install slack dependencies pip install apache-airflow[slack]" but this doesn't install SlackWebHookOperator as the import throws a “Cannot find reference slack_webhook_operator in *init*.py” error. Is there any other installation I am missing?

`from airflow.contrib.operators.slack_webhook_operator import SlackWebHookOperator`

I expect the SlackWebHookOperator to be able to be referenced.

I have tried installing slackclient dependency but it didn't installed SlackWebHookOperator as I cannot reference it.
[SlackWebHookOperator is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO0nu.png)

Comment: That import statement looks correct to me. Which version of Airflow are you on? It was only added as part of [AIRFLOW-2217](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2217) under 1.10.0.

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks for responding. I am using version 1.10.1 which being a latest version should have it if I am not mistaken. I am running airflow on a container and got another issue " Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/vlproxy_dag.py] No module named 'slackclient' " following the tutorial I didn't knew I needed this slackclient dependency.

Comment: Ah that's where the author's mention of "Remember to install slack dependencies pip install apache-airflow[slack]" comes in. See https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.1/setup.py#L209, when you specify the installation extras of `slack`, that's where it'll tell Airflow to install the additional `slackclient` package needed by the operator.

Comment: @DuaneLausell Just based on a glance could you confirm that your capitalization is correct? I see `WebHook` in your import but looking at [github](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.1/airflow/contrib/operators/slack_webhook_operator.py#L25) I see `Webhook` (lowercase h)

Comment: @DanielHuang I installed slackclient dependency but I still cannot reference SlackWebHookOperator I added a screenshot to the qs.

Comment: @qfwfq I tried Webhook also but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

**For Airflow 2.x**

`airflow.contrib.operators.slack_webhook_operator` has been deprecated.

---

You'd first have to install `apache-airflow-providers-slack`:

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-slack
```

and finally import `SlackWebhookOperator`:

```
from airflow.providers.slack.operators.slack_webhook import SlackWebhookOperator
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from airflow.providers.slack.operators.slack_webhook import SlackWebhookOperator
```